# Mathematica code to find R (upper triangular matrix) in QR decomposition using reflection method

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, algorithm

I am trying to write Mathematica code to find $R $  (upper triangular matrix) in $   A=QR $ $A \in \Bbb{R}^{n\times n}$decomposition using reflection method. 
 I wrote for $3 \times 3$ matrix. 
Any tips for write it for $n$ dimension.

Comment: How did you implement your Householder reflections?

Comment: Finding the rotation angle and Q[b_] := Module[{\[Theta]},
  \[Theta] = Theta[b];
  R[\[Theta]].( {
     {1, 0},
     {0, -1}
    } ).R[-\[Theta]]]

Comment: Why not try to write a method for the Householder reflection for $n$-dimensions before anything else?

Comment: Have you see the `Method` option of [`Orthogonalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orthogonalize.html) and the [Matrix Decompositions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MatrixDecompositions.html) guide?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a pretty basic (and **inefficient**) routine for getting the QR decomposition of a matrix via Householder reflection:

```
qrd[mat_?MatrixQ] := Module[{r = mat, h, m, n, q, v, v2},
    {m, n} = Dimensions[r]; q = IdentityMatrix[m];
    Do[v = PadLeft[r[[k ;;, k]], m];
       v2 = v - SparseArray[{k -> Norm[v]}, m];
       h = If[! TrueQ[Norm[v2, ∞] == 0], ReflectionMatrix[v2], IdentityMatrix[m]];
       q = q.h; r = h.r,
       {k, n}];
    {q, r}]
```

which returns the $\mathbf Q$ and $\mathbf R$ factors in a list.

It could be made more efficient by exploiting the structure of the Householder update (see e.g. Golub and Van Loan or Stewart for how to do that), but I'll leave that for the OP or someone else to do.

Comment: Thank you and I am trying to do so.

Comment: Of course, since `QRDecomposition[]` is actually built-in, the code here is more of a toy than anything else.