# Performing Hessenberg decomposition on a symbolic matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I am trying to calculate the Hessenberg decomposition of a symbolic matrix

$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -\mathrm ia & 0 & b \cos x \\
\mathrm ia & 0 & \mathrm ic \sin x & 0 \\
0 & -\mathrm ic \sin x & 0 & -\mathrm ia \\
b \cos x & 0 & \mathrm ia & 0
\end{pmatrix},
$$

where $a,b,c,x$ are symbolic variables. Computing the Hessenberg decomposition for a numerical matrix `A` can be easily obtained using

```
{P, T} = HessenbergDecomposition[A];
```

How can I obtain `P` and `T` for my symbolic matrix `A`?

Comment: Might consider instead using `Eigensystem`.

Comment: `Eigensystem` gives eigenvectors (full matrix) and eigenvalues (diagonal matrix) but not the Hessenberg form of my matrix.

Comment: Right, `Eigensystem` returns an eigensystem. But it can serve in similar use cases to a Hessenberg decomposition and moreover works for symbolic input. `HessenbergDecomposition` is strictly numeric. Another alternative might be `JordanDecomposition` by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not overly difficult to write a simple (but **inefficient**) method for symbolically performing Hessenberg decomposition, based on repeated similarity transformations with Householder matrices. It is interesting to compare the routine for QR decomposition in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133905) with the Hessenberg decomposition function given below:

```
hesdec[mat_?SquareMatrixQ] := Module[{h = mat, r, n, q, v, v2},
   n = Length[h]; q = IdentityMatrix[n];
   Do[v = PadLeft[h[[k + 1 ;;, k]], n];
      v2 = v - SparseArray[{k + 1 -> Norm[v]}, n];
      r = If[! TrueQ[Norm[v2, ∞] == 0], ReflectionMatrix[v2], IdentityMatrix[n]];
      q = q.r; h = r.h.r, {k, n - 2}];
   {q, h}]
```

Applied to your matrix,

```
{qq, hh} = hesdec[{{0, -I a, 0, b Cos[x]}, {I a, 0, I c Sin[x], 0},
                   {0, -I c Sin[x], 0, -I a}, {b Cos[x], 0, I a, 0}}];
```

one however obtains expressions of horrendous complexity:

```
LeafCount[hs = Simplify[ComplexExpand[hh, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]]]
   3583

LeafCount[qs = Simplify[ComplexExpand[qq, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]]]
   134
```

What to do with these matrices afterwards is up to you. But you might appreciate a little that writing functions like these so that expression swell is minimized is not trivial.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks!